# Adding GestureRecognizer in loop doesn't work Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

I am trying to loop through my different views and add gesture recognizers to them. But this does not add the gestures to them:

```
for i in numberOfViews {
     view.viewWithTag(i)?.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}
```

But when I do it outside of the loop it works:

```
view.viewWithTag(8)?.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

I verifed this is true by looping through the gestures added

```
var listofgest = view.viewWithTag(8)?.gestureRecognizers ?? []
for each in listofgest {
    print("this is a gest \(each)")
}
```

Comment: Don't add swift3/swift4/swift5 tags unless you have questions specific to those flavors of Swift. the regular `swift` tag is what you want.

Comment: You can't add a single gesture to multiple views. If you do (like in your for loop), the last view will always have the gesture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that a gesture recognizer can only be added to a single view. Your code is trying to add the same gesture recognizer, `gesture`, to all the views in `view.viewWithTag(i)` (where i is an array of integers?). Don't do that.

Create a separate gesture recognizer for each view that you want to have it's own gesture recognizer.

Otherwise, add the gesture recognizer to the superview. Then it will fire when you tap anywhere on the superview.

Comment: Thank you. Declaring the variable in the loop fixes the issue, as each view controller will have its own gesture recognizer.